# checking the format of a date in csv file

Tags: java, date, csv, simpledateformat

I am parsing an csv file , and I am able to do it successfully through csv beans 0.5 jar now I have a query is that in my csv file there is date column as shown below..

```
Name|date
AAA|02-Mar-2012
BBB|09-Mar-2012
```

Now as shown above in csv file there is a column date , but now I need to put a formatter for it so that date should always be in this above shown format`(02-Mar-2012)` , if any how the date format is not there as shown above format then I must throw a customized exception , please advise how to write a method that will have a functionality of a formatter in it, I have a seprate class in which I want to put it as a separate method and that method functionality would be to check the format , please advise 
I wa trying something like this `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-00-00-00");`

folks any response would be highly appreciated thanks in advance, please advise

Comment: Can we see your parsing code ?

Comment: Just FYI, you might want to check out [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) and its `ParseDate` cell processor

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public boolean isValidDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    Date testDate;
    try {
        testDate = sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!sdf.format(testDate).equals(date)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```